# How can I create a loop for this data?

Tags: r

The problem I have goes like this: I have experience with R, but unfortunately loops aren't my strong side. I want to create a loop that shortens the following:

```
library(wbstats)

enrg_cons = wb(country = "all", indicator = "EG.USE.PCAP.KG.OE")
gdp = wb(country = "all", indicator = "NY.GDP.PCAP.CD")


#Separating members of the OECD
#Australia
enrg_cons_AUS = enrg_cons[which(enrg_cons$iso3c == "AUS" & enrg_cons$date >=1995 & enrg_cons$date <=2014), 
                          names(enrg_cons) %in% c("date", "value", "country")]
gdp_AUS = gdp[which(gdp$iso3c == "AUS" & gdp$date >=1995 & gdp$date<=2014), names(gdp) %in% c("date", "value", "country")]
#Austria
enrg_cons_AUT = enrg_cons[which(enrg_cons$iso3c == "AUT" & enrg_cons$date >=1995 & enrg_cons$date <=2014), 
                          names(enrg_cons) %in% c("date", "value", "country")]
gdp_AUT = gdp[which(gdp$iso3c == "AUT" & gdp$date >=1995 & gdp$date<=2014), names(gdp) %in% c("date", "value", "country")]
#Belgium
enrg_cons_BEL = enrg_cons[which(enrg_cons$iso3c == "BEL" & enrg_cons$date >=1995 & enrg_cons$date <=2014), 
                          names(enrg_cons) %in% c("date", "value", "country")]
gdp_BEL = gdp[which(gdp$iso3c == "BEL" & gdp$date >=1995 & gdp$date<=2014), names(gdp) %in% c("date", "value", "country")]
#Canada
enrg_cons_CAN = enrg_cons[which(enrg_cons$iso3c == "CAN" & enrg_cons$date >=1995 & enrg_cons$date <=2014), 
                          names(enrg_cons) %in% c("date", "value", "country")]
```

I want to investigate GDP and energy consumption for about 20 OECD countries and I want to create a nice loop that extracts me the values from the code above without writing it for every country. I want to also create a loop for the following command:

```
#Augmented Dickey-Fuller(ADF) test
adf.test(log(gdp_AUS$value), k = 0)$p.value; adf.test(diff(log(enrg_cons_AUS$value)), k = 0)
adf.test(log(gdp_AUT$value), k = 0)$p.value; adf.test(diff(log(enrg_cons_AUT$value)), k = 0)
```

again for all the countries I'm researching. I hope the information is sufficient and reproducible, if not, let me know and I will do my best to improve it! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this. The one which fits most easily into your current workflow is probably the `assign` function.

## Assign solution

First package the data extraction into a pair of functions:

```
get_country_enrg_cons <- function(country) {
  enrg_cons[
    enrg_cons$iso3c == country & enrg_cons$date >=1995 & enrg_cons$date <=2014, 
    c("date", "value", "country")
  ]
}

get_country_gdp <- function(country) {
  gdp[
    gdp$iso3c == country & gdp$date >=1995 & gdp$date<=2014, 
    c("date", "value", "country")
  ]
}
```

We can then loop over a list of countries and assign the results to variables created using `paste`:

```
countries <- c("AUS", "AUT", "BEL", "CAN")

for (country in countries) {
  assign(paste0("energ_cons_", country), get_country_enrg_cons(country))
  assign(paste0("gdp_", country), get_country_gdp(country))
}
```

You should end up with the tables you need in your global environment.

The Dickey-Fuller test map then be applied like so:

```
library(tseries)

get_adf_test <- function(country_gdp, country_enrg_cons) {
  adf.test(
    log(country_gdp$value), k = 0)$p.value;
    adf.test(diff(log(country_enrg_cons$value)), k = 0)
}

for (country in countries) {
  country_gdp <- eval(parse(text = paste0("gdp_", country)))
  country_enrg_cons <- eval(parse(text = paste0("energ_cons_", country)))
  assign(paste0("adf_", country), get_adf_test(country_gdp, country_enrg_cons))
}
```

I'll be the first to admit, however, that this solution isn't exactly elegant. A simpler solution is a table based solution which keeps all variables in a single data structure.

## Tidyverse solution

Using the functions defined above, we can create a table with list columns containing the output data frames, as well as the model output.

```
library(tidyverse)

countries_df <- tibble(country = c("AUS", "AUT", "BEL", "CAN"))

countries_df <- countries_df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    country_gdp = list(get_country_gdp(country)),
    country_enrg_cons = list(get_country_enrg_cons(country)),
    country_adf_test = list(get_adf_test(country_gdp, country_enrg_cons))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The model outputs can now be accessed using subset operations:

```
countries_df %>% 
  filter(country == "AUS") %>% 
  pull(country_adf_test)

#   Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test
# 
# data:  diff(log(country_enrg_cons$value))
# Dickey-Fuller = -3.1949, Lag order = 0, p-value = 0.1172
# alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I tried the code and it works like a charm. I agree that it is a bit lengthy in terms of data frames in the global environment, but it does the job. I get the results and it shortens the code quite a lot. Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is largely an aggregation by group. For each `isoc`, you are interested in a summary statistic. Instead of creating 250+ objects in the environment, we can aggregate which here is done using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(gdp)
gdp[between(date, 1995, 2014) & iso3c != 'SOM', 
    adf.test(log(value), k = 0)$p.value,
    by = iso3c]

      iso3c         V1
     <char>      <num>
  1:    ARB 0.75501918
  2:    CSS 0.49522577
  3:    CEB 0.73116544
  4:    EAR 0.92497081
  5:    EAS 0.99000000
 ---                  
253:    VIR 0.97525907
254:    PSE 0.95374047
255:    YEM 0.05792444
256:    ZMB 0.95657239
257:    ZWE 0.79529898
```

Now you may have noticed the part `iso3C != 'SOM'`. There were some errors as there did not appear to be enough observations to allow for the calculation. Therefore, a more generalized [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach would be:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(gdp)
gdp[between(date, 1995, 2014), 
    if (.N > 5L) adf.test(log(value), k = 0)$p.value,
    by = iso3c]

setDT(enrg_cons)
enrg_cons[between(date, 1995, 2014),
          if (.N > 5L) adf.test(diff(log(value)), k = 0),
          by = iso3c]
```

Data and setup:

```
library(wbstats)
library(tseries)

enrg_cons = wb(country = "all", indicator = "EG.USE.PCAP.KG.OE")
gdp = wb(country = "all", indicator = "NY.GDP.PCAP.CD")
```

Comment: Thank you, too, @Cole! I have two more questions now that I have tried your code:
1) What does the following part of your code do: 
```
if (.N > 5)
```
I don't quite get that. And also
2) if I want to extract only the statistic for the countries I'm interested in could I include an argument somewhere in the code you provided? I tried adding:
```
by = iso3c == countries
```
where countries are specified as "countries <- c("AUS", "AUT", "BEL", "CAN")", but this does not work which I believe is because you cannot add more specifications with "==" after using "by". Thanks again!

Comment: The ```.N > 5``` is saying for each country we need more than 5 records. In the first part you can see the exclusion of SOM. Instead you would do ```iso3c %in% c("AUS", "CAN", ...)``` and all the other countries you are interested in